# Magento2 production mode error magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, html, production-mode, minify

I got below error on my category pages and product pages after setting minify html to yes:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘<‘, expecting end of file” magento2 production mode

What should i do?

Comment: Can you please share the exact error message. Either some of your phtml files haven't generated properly in var/view_preprocessed

Answer (score 2):

The cause of such errors is hidden in the template files. In the following commented code

```
1 <?php //echo "this is an unwanted php code";?>
```

there is no space between the semicolon “;” and the closing tag of php i.e. “?>” which causes the error.

For the above code, when the HTML file is minified, the closing tag of php is considered as a part of the commented code which is not included in the minified file and throws the error.

So, while commenting a php code in a phtml file, make sure that there is a space before the closing tag of php as done in the code below-

```
1 <?php //echo "this is an unwanted php code"; ?>
```

Doing this will avoid the error due to minification of HTML file.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: found it before and tried but not solved